# Check if fragment displayed as dialog to change click listener behavior

Tags: android, onclick, android-dialogfragment

I am creating an app in which the user should be able add people for meetings.

The structure consists of several fragments managed in the same activity (`list_people, person_detail, create_meeting`).

I would like to reuse the fragment showing the list of people as a dialog in the `create_meeting` fragment. And add a person to a meeting by clicking on the person item.

When the `list_people` fragment is embedded in the view, a click on a person item replace the `list_people` fragment with a `person_detail` fragment. This behavior is already implemented with an interface for the main activity.

I am looking for a solution to change the behavior of  the click listener whether the `list_people` fragment is displayed as an embedded fragment or as a dialog. Any ideas of how I could do that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found a solution. It is to use a constructor (`newInstance`) for the fragment in which you can pass variables.

```
public class ListPeopleFragment extends Fragment {

public static ListPeopleFragment newInstance(boolean nested){
    ListPeopleFragment f = new ListPeopleFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putBoolean("nested", nested);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_people, container, false);

    boolean nested = false;
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null)
    {
        nested = getArguments().getBoolean("nested");
    } 

    displayListViewPeople(view, nested);

    return view;
}
}
```

The `displayListViewPeople` set the click listener depending on the value of `nested`.

You instantiate the fragment this way:

```
ListPeopleFragment nestedFrag = ListPeopleFragment.newInstance(true);
```